# Cannot Resolve symbol 'BottomSheetDialog'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

as the title says im lost in android studios with the BottomSheetDialog, it seems to work like this for everyone else online but not for me...
example: `BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this);`

The BottomSheetDialog turns red (doesnt matter where it is) and complains about "Cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: That's probably missing an `import` statement. Take a look at the very top of the examples you're using, it should be there somewhere. Also, probably Alt+Enter can auto-fix it for you when your cursor is in or next to the word.

Comment: thanks for the post, If I hold my mouse over it it suggests that I should "Create a class" out of it.

Comment: just restart your IDE :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BottomSheetDialog is a part of Google Material Design library. You need to add that library to your project using

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

Add the above line to build.gradle file in the app folder.
After doing the sync successfully, you should be able to import the BottomSheetDialog by hovering your cursor over the word.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! you are a legend! after adding that + syncing project with gradle files it gave me the option to import

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions to your problem:

1- pass the context into the constructor and not the whole activity :

```
BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getApplicationContext());
```

2-
this item need the bottom sheet library in you dependencies (in your build.graddle file , in the section dependencies {} ) :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

then sync with graddle ( at the top right of the screen ) . you can now put your cursor over it and you are able to import the class.